# Datatype trouble in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data something like this.

```
70.6
70.60
70.7
70.70
```

I can't use varchar as I need to perform arithmetic operations (>,< or floor), when I used float all records change to 70.7 and 70.6 from 70.70 and 70.60

When I changed to decimal(2,2), then all 70.6 records changed to 70.60.

Please suggest which data type suits for me.

Business need to retain 70.6 as it is and 70.60 as it is.
Currently data is in dataware house and stored in varchar.
I am preparing data mart and written query like

```
Result1 = CASE WHEN Dia = ''   OR Dia > 28 OR M.Dia < 6 THEN 'Dia' END,
Result2 = CASE WHEN Width = '' OR Width > 16 OR M.Width < 3 THEN 'Width' END,
Result6 = CASE WHEN Bore] = '' OR FLOOR(LOG10(REVERSE(ABS(M.[Center Bore])+1)))+1 <> 2  THEN 'Bore' END,
```

Comment: From the mathematical point of view, there is no difference between `70.6` and `70.60`. If your business rules must treat these values as different values, you have no choice but to keep them as strings.

Comment: `70.7` and `70.70` is the same value. What exactly is your problem? Why don't you just format them accordingly when _displaying_ the data?

Comment: I  need to create a ssrs report and pull data from warehouse and need to check 
whether data in a column is matching the rule. in Dataware house column in a table 
used varchar but as i need to perform many arithmatic and logical check i want to change the datatype.

Comment: when i used float, trailing 0 is missing, and when i used decimal or numeric, 0 is getting added in the last
please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

From the mathematical point of view, there is no difference between `70.6` and `70.60`. If your business rules must treat these values as different values, and you want to also be able to perform mathematical operations of them, you should keep them as decimal in your database, and I suggest adding a `tinyint` column that will specify the number of decimal digits of the original string value.

create a stored procedure that will get the value as string, calculate the number of decimal digits, convert the string to decimal, and save both of these values into the database.

When selecting the value you convert it to string and manipulate the decimal digits as you please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Convert(float, **)` to convert the data from `nvarchar`.

I don't think there would be any difference can occur when your data is either `60.6` or `60.60` while performing `arithmetic operation (>,< or floor)`

```
select convert(float, '60.6') as val
Output: 60.6
```

as you mentioned in the comment

```
because I am checking data have only 1 digit after decimal
```

Then you can form get such a string using `charindex` and `left`.

```
select left(val, charindex('.', val) + 1) as new_val
from (select '60.6666' as val) as x
```

Input string : `60.6666`
Output String : `60.6`

now you can use

```
convert(float, new_val) as val
```

like,

```
select convert(float, left(val, charindex('.', val) + 1)) as val
from (select '60.6666' as val) as x
```

Comment: i used 
convert(FLOAT, Dia)

then even 60.60 is also converting to 60.6 which is wrong as per business requirement

Comment: any suggestion techie.

Comment: because i am checking data have only 1 digit after decimal.CASE WHEN Bore] = '' OR FLOOR(LOG10(REVERSE(ABS(M.[Center Bore])+1)))+1 <> 2

Comment: hi , you have hard coded 60.60, will it work for other value of same pattern in a column. Please suggest.